# Is there a free pgp key dumping program?

Tags: dump, public-key, pgp, openpgp, public-fields

is there any pgp key dumping program like http://www.pgpdump.net/ that also shows the MPI values as well as the other information? the linked website's program will print out `...` for the long MPI, which is perfectly logical, but I want to see the values since my program is for some reason getting all but one part right (reading an elgamal public key), and its messing with everything that comes afterwards. i want to see where im off by a few bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gpg --list-packets --debug-all should show MPI values.

Answer (score 2):

[pgpdump.net](http://www.pgpdump.net/about.html) links to the source code of `pgpdump`. Perhaps you could find the part where `...` is written and change it in a local copy of the program.